# Python: setting negative values in list to 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

This seems like it would be simple, but I am having an issue with setting negative numbers in a list to 0. Here is my code:

```
def subtract_lists(list1, list2):
    list3 = list()
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
            list3.append(list1[i]-list2[i])
    if i < 0:
            i = 0
    else:
            i = i
    return list3
```

I am using this function when making stacked bar charts with matplotlib. Essentially, some values in list2 are larger than values in list1. For the data I have it doesn't make sense to have negative values. Essentially anything with a negative value would just plot as one solid bar.

EDIT: Just wanted to add that the top of the graph is list3.

EDIT 2: Thank you everyone for the help. I ended up using this due to the simplicity:

```
def subtract_lists(list1, list2):
    list3 = list()
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
            list3.append(max(list1[i]-list2[i], 0))
    return list3
```

However I appreciate all the solutions and help, I am going to try some of the other examples just for a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 list3 = []
 for i in range(len(list1)):
     list3.append(max(list1[i] - list2[i], 0))
```

or

```
 list3 = [ max(li1-li2, 0) for li1, li2 in zip(list1, list2) ]
```

The `zip` enables to iterate through two lists at the same time so that `li1` and `li2` are list items form the same position of the list. IMO this is the most Pythonic way of doing it, and in this case it's probably also the fastest way, if we have two lists. The `max` takes care of negative numbers, because then zero is greater than `li1-li2` and is put into `list3`.

The solution given by `jsw` is a nice solution, but the conversion from a list to `ndarray` (NumPy array) is a slow one. And, of course, NumPy is not (unfortunately) part of the standard Python distribution.

Comment: "And, of course, NumPy is not (unfortunately) part of the standard Python distribution": but `numpy` is a dependency of `matplotlib`, so it's probably available.

Comment: A verry good point!! (I may have to see an opthtalmologist, I gather.) In that case the NumPy answer is probably the best.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to change the list to a `numpy` `array`.  Then the subtraction is easy and clear, plus you can use `numpy.clip` to change negative values to 0.  `numpy` arithmetic is also much, much faster (if that's a concern in this case, which seems unlikely) than iterating over python lists.

```
import numpy as np

ar1 = np.array(list1)
ar2 = np.array(list2)

ar3 = np.clip(ar1 - ar2, 0, None)
```

If you don't want to use numpy, then just change this line

```
list3.append(list1[i] - list2[i])
```

to this

```
list3.append(max(list1[i] - list2[i], 0))
```

Finally, when you're iterating over lists to make a new list, it is far more idiomatically python to use a list comprehension:

```
list3 = [max(item1 - item2, 0) for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Of course, if the lists are moderately large, then you have to concern yourself with the fact that `zip` actually makes a copy of the lists.  So if memory usage is too large with `zip`, you can use `izip` from the `itertools` module.  It's just a drop-in replacement (in this case) for `zip`:

```
from itertools import izip
list3 = [max(item1 - item2, 0) for item1, item2 in izip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `i` to zero, not the content of `list3[i]`.

```
if list3[i] < 0:
    list3[i] = 0
```

Your `else` block is setting `i=i`, which does nothing. You are also lacking one level of indentation for this check, the correct indentation would look like this:

```
def subtract_lists(list1, list2):
    list3 = list()
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(list1[i]-list2[i])
        if list3[i] < 0:
            list3[i] = 0
return list3
```

However, I think it would be clearer to write the function like this:

```
def subtract_lists(list1, list2):        
    list3 = []
    for a,b in zip(list1, list2):
        diff = a - b 
        list3.append(diff if diff > 0 else 0)
    return list3
```

There are of course more concise solutions (check DrV's answer).

Comment: The indentation needs to be fixed, too; the check needs to be made on every iteration of the for loop, not once, after the loop is finished.